# How do I explicitly split a Dataset tuple in Tensorflow's functional API into two separate layers from just one input layer?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, functional-api, typespec

**Context**
The input to my model is a BatchDataset object called `dataset_train`, and it is batched to yield `(training_data, label)`.

For some of the machinery in my model, I need to be able to split the Dataset tuple inside the model and independently access both the data and the label. This is a single input model with multiple outputs, so I am using Tensorflow's Functional API. For the sake of reproducibility, I am working with timeseries, so a toy dataset would look like this:

```
time = np.arange(1000)
data = np.random.randn(1000)
label = np.random.randn(1000)


training_data = np.zeros(shape=(time.size,2))
training_data[:,0] = time
training_data[:,1] = data


dataset_train = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
      data = training_data,
      targets = label,
      batch_size = batch_size, 
      sequence_length = sequence_length,
      sequence_stride = 1,
  )
```

Note: Sequence Length and batch_size are additional semi-arbitrary hyperparameters that are not important for the purposes of this question.

**Question**
How do I split apart the Dataset in Tensorflow's Functional API into the training data element and the label element?
Here is pseudocode of what I am looking for:

```
input = Single Input Layer that defines something capable of accepting dataset_train

training_data  = input.element_spec[0]
label = input.element_spec[1]
```

After that point, my model can perform it's actions on training_data and label independently.

**First Solution I tried:**
I first started by trying to define two input layers and pass each element of the dataset tuple to each input layer, and the act on each input layer independently.

```
training_data = tf.keras.Input(shape=(sequence_length,2))
label = tf.keras.Input(shape = sequence_length)

#model machinery

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs = [training_data, label],
    outputs = [output_1, output_2]
)

#model machinery

history = model.fit(dataset_train, epochs = 500)
```

The first problem I had with this is that I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer "model_5" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, 2) dtype=float64>]
```

This is a problem, because if I actually pass the model a dictionary of datasets (nevermind that this isn't supported) then I introduce a circular dependency where in order to use `model.predict`, it expects labels for the inputs to `model.predict`. In other words, I need the  answers to get the answers. Because I need to pass it only a single Dataset to prevent introducing this circular dependency (tensorflow implicitly assumes that the second element in a Dataset is the label, and doesn't require Datasets with labels for `model.predict`), I decided to abandon this strategy for unpacking the Input layer directly within the functional API for the model.

**Second Solution I tried:**
I thought maybe I could unpack the Dataset using the `.get_single_element()` method in the following code excerpt

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape = (sequence_length, 2))
training_dataset, label = input.get_single_element()
```

This gave the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'get_single_element'
```

I then thought the problem was that because the symbolic tensor wasn't of type Dataset, I needed to define the input layer to expect a Dataset. After reading through the documentation and spending ~9 hours messing around, I realized that `tf.keras.Input` takes an argument called `type_spec`, which allows the user to specify exactly the type of symbolic tensor to create (I think - I'm still a little shaky on understanding exactly what's going on and I'm more than a little sleep deprived, which isn't helping). As it turns out there's a way to generate the `type_spec` from the dataset itself, so I did that to make sure that I wasn't making a mistake in generating it.

```
input = tf.keras.Input(tensor = dataset_train)
training_dataset, label = input.get_single_element()
```

Which gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I'm not really sure why I get this error, but I tried to circumvent it by explicitly defining the type_spec in the Input layer

```
input = tf.keras.Input(type_spec: tf.data.DatasetSpec.from_value(dataset_train))
training_dataset, label = input.get_single_element()
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: KerasTensor only supports TypeSpecs that have a shape field; got DatasetSpec, which does not have a shape.
```

I also had tried to make the DatasetSpec manually instead of generating it using `.from_value` earlier and had gotten the same error. I thought then it was just because I was messing it up, but now that I've gotten this error from `.from_value`, I'm beginning to suspect that this line of solutions won't work because DatasetSpec implicitly is missing a shape. I might also be confused, because performing `dataset_train.element_spec` clearly reveals that the dataset does have a shape, so I'm not sure why Tensorflow can't infer from it.

Any help in furthering either of those non-functional solutions so that I can explicitly access the training_data and label separately from an input Dataset inside the Functional API would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to use the labels as an input to your model?

Comment: Not exactly that I want to use the labels as an input to the model, I want to input a Dataset containing corresponding training_data and labels to the model. I'd like to be able to separate them inside the model and act on them separately for the machinery in my custom loss function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split your dataset into x_train and y_train datasets! Keras will do this for you. All you need need to do is reformat your `(input, output_1_label, output_2_label)` tuple to `(input, {'named_output_1': output_1_label, 'named_output_2': output_2_label)`. I did my reformatting inside a tf.data.Dataset.map call.

I assume you wanted to split your tuple to call
`model.fit(x=x_train, y={'out1' y_train_1, 'out2': y_train_2}, ...)`

Instead, with your input/output tuple you just call
`model.fit(x_train_tuples ...)`